# Ubuntu 20.04 gateway, iptables NAT and port forwarding

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, nat, gateway

i am in a maze, i try in vain to setup the rules to be able to acces from internet my internal web server (192.168.12.10).

at home, i have an Ubuntu 20.04 gateway (192.168.12.1) with two interfaces :

- eth1 : for external / internet with public IP like 123.123.123.123
- br0 : for internal with private IP

I have also some laptops.

Everything seems to work fine with the following iptables rules. BY default, i have no access from outside to the internal.

`iptables -vnL --line-number`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 373 packets, 25051 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      101  9891 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    16175 3203K ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     2517  342K ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    58714   11M ACCEPT     all  --  br0    eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5    60179  155M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "FW FW denied: "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2098 packets, 234K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`iptables -t nat -vnL --line-number`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2209 packets, 192K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1215 packets, 89074 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 648 packets, 59463 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     3807  290K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

My trouble is that i can't set the right rules to be able to acccess to my web server from the outside.

I had two rules in the FORWARD chain and two rules in the PREROUTING chain.

`iptables -vnL --line-number`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 100 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      155 14331 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    21779 4281K ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     2953  401K ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    67303   12M ACCEPT     all  --  br0    eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.12.10        ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:80
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.12.10        ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:443
7    69670  168M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8        1    60 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "FW FW denied: "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 1208 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`iptables -t nat -vnL --line-number`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 211 packets, 19200 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        1    40 DNAT       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.12.10:80
2        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.12.10:443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 169 packets, 9937 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 1677 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 813 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     4419  338K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The result is always the same.

When i try, for example, `curl -I 123.123.123.123` the request goes to the webserver inside the gateway. When is up, i recieve an answer, when is down `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 123.123.123.123 port 80: Connection refused`

My request never reach the internal web server 192.168.12.10.

UFW is down and i set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1.

If someone can help me ?

Thank's

Comment: It looks O.K. You say "when is down ... Connection refused". Is that not what is expected?

Comment: I think you meant when the web server in the gateway computer is down the packets do not get to the computer at 192.168.12.10, and "Connection refused" is returned. When the web server in the gateway computer is up, it responds instead of 192.168.12.10. It that correct? I still can not see what is wrong with the rules. Add more logging, just for testing.

Comment: Exactly. It's like the "curl" request never passthrough the gateway. Do you have some advice to add more logging ?

Comment: From your listing, we see that one packet did go through DNAT, but it did not hit the related FORWARD rule. Odd. Is it in the log file under "FW FW denied:"? I would start adding debug logging rules everywhere in the port 80 rules, and use port 80 to debug. Myself, I would take out the cstate stuff and also specify the output interface.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly an expert, but is your firewall blocking access to the required ports? Try running

`firewall-cmd --list-ports`

and see if your port 80 and 443 are open.

Comment: i did not install "firewalld", i will look at it. thanks.